# Javascript/React not connecting to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is the second page of a website I'm creating. The first page is the landing page and has react rendered buttons in it that work perfectly. But for some reason I'm not able to use either plain javascript or react on the second webpage. I've checked the path and spelling but nothing works.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

console.log('Hello world!');
ReactDOM.render(<h1>JavaScript</h1>, document.getElementById('qwerty'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Teacher</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='qwerty'>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>

  </div>
  <script src='./src/signup.js' type='text.jsx'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Manav and welcome to SO. React and JSX are supersets of JavaScript, meaning they add new functionality with new syntaxes. But these syntaxes are not supported natively by browsers. That's why there is always a *build* step that converts JSX to JS, which the browser can run. Look into the React documentation on how to setup your build process.

Answer (score -1):

You have three problems:

1. Browsers only support `import` in scripts declared as modules
2. Browsers do not support JSX at all
3. `text.jsx` isn’t a valid value for the `type` attribute

You need to convert your code which uses JSX and imports into something that a browser will support.

[The official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) offers two approaches to this. Setup Option 2: Local Development Environment takes more work to get going, but gives you a more efficient result in the end.

Comment: Hey! Even without the import statements and type='text/javascript' I'm unale to use my javascript. Is it not possible to use plain javascript in a React.js app?

Comment: @ManavNeema — If you remove the import statements, then you aren’t even trying to load the React libraries you are depending on. If you claim it is JS then it will try to execute the JSX as JS… which it isn’t, so it will error. You could, in theory, use plain JS in a React app (which would essentially be writing the code that a transpiler would generate) but I’ve never seen anyone attempt that since it would mean giving up the very powerful JSX syntax that is one of the primary benefits of React.

Comment: Here's the link to my github repo: https://github.com/manavneema/competitive-coding-platform can you please check it out and tell me what the problem is and how can I connect my Javascript(reactjs) to HTML